# Typescript: Filter out rest parameter

Tags: typescript

I want to dynamically remove the type **number** from the tuple (tuple get from function parameters), but the number can be a rest type:

```js
function myFn(num1: number, text: string, ...nums: number[]): void {}

type Args = Parameters<typeof myFn>; // [number, string, ...number[]] <- Will be using similar result in future examples
```

I have a type that filters the entire tuple through recursion:

```js
type Filter<T extends any[], U> = T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer H, ...infer R] ?
    H extends U ? Filter<R, U> : [H, ...Filter<R, U>] : T;
```

And it works great for simple types:

```js
type Args = [number, string, number, Symbol, number];
type Result = Filter<Args, number>; // [string, Symbol];
```

But when a rest type appears in a tuple, its type does not get to filter either "number" or "number[]":

```js
type Args = [number, string, ...number[]];

type Result1 = Filter<Args, number>; // [string, ...number[]]
type Result2 = Filter<Args, number[]>; // [number, string, ...number[]]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgG2BATgHgCpQgD2QOwBMBnKAQ3xAG0BdAGigFUA%20KAXii1wJKlqgD8fGlABcAKChTO2PBCKkqcfADNUUABIMAdLuVqUUAEoiBk6Rtk9SjQbETJ0RhizF8tUXdvhJUaZ0zMIqKcANzi4qCQUACCKADmpBxU%20ACuALYARqgMxMAoyvE6umlZqLQ04ZHg0EYQxKlIAIzs9r7ocYkMpdkozKFQAPSDfHkF%20EWeJRm9FdXRdQ1IAEytPo5oncTdM%20U0-UMjKbsoufmFxdo9ezTiQA)

What could be the problem and how can it be solved?

Are rest parameters have a different type?

Why he pass the "any" or "number[]" filter checks by "extends"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```js
type Args = [number, string, ...number[]];

type Filter<T extends any[], F> = T extends [] ? [] :
    T extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail] ?
    Head extends F ? Filter<Tail, F> : [Head, ...Filter<Tail, F>] : [];

type Result1 = Filter<Args, number>; // [string]
type Result2 = Filter<Args, number[]>; // [number, string]

type Result3 = Filter<Args, number | number[]>; // [string]
type Result4 = Filter<Args, number | number[] | string>; // []
```

I have replaced your last return type `T` with empty array `[]`

Rest element must be last in the tuple.